# how do i stop a form submit with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form [here](http://posnation.com/shop_pos/) and i dont want them to go to the next page without certain selections

```
<form method="post" action="step2/" id="form1">
....
....
....
<input type="submit" class="submit notext" value="Next" />
```

and here is my jquery

```
$('.submit').click(function(e) {
    var business = $(".business_type_select").find('.container strong').text();
    alert(business);
    if(business == "Select Business Type"){
        alert("BusinessBusinessBusiness");
        e.preventDefault;
        return false;
    }
});
```

any ideas what i am missing to get this to stop submitting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the `submit` event:

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e) {
    var business = $(".business_type_select").find('.container strong').text();
    alert(business);
    if(business == "Select Business Type"){
        alert("BusinessBusinessBusiness");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also, the `e.preventDefault()` is a function, but is redundant as the `return false` will work just the same.

Comment: `e.preventDefault` should be a function call

Answer (score 5):

`preventDefault` is a function - use `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @tamer: Try a combination of my answer with @Jesse's.. Bind to the `.submit` event, using `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 2):

There are sometimes issues with `.preventDefault()` in IE try adding this:

```
if (e.preventDefault)      // checks to see if the event has a preventDefault method
    e.preventDefault();
else
    e.returnValue = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#formID").submit(function(e) {
    var business = $(".business_type_select").find('.container strong').text();
    alert(business);
    if(business == "Select Business Type"){
        alert("BusinessBusinessBusiness");
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your asp.net MVC razor form looks something like this:-

You can use (document) ID to validate form values using JavaScript. JavaScript validations fire prior to validations done using HTML Helpers ( @ValidationFor etc)..

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyRequestAction", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
code goes here...
}
$(document).submit(function (e) {
    var catVal = $("#Category").val();
    if (catVal == "") {
        alert("Please select Category!");
        return false;
    }
    if (catVal == "--Select One--") {
        alert("Please select Category!");
        return false;
    }
});
```